# One word for a harmful idea/plan

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there **one** word for *a harmful idea/plan*? (All that comes to my mind is *evil/wicked idea*, but it's two words, and anyway it's actually a synonym for *brilliant/cunning idea*.)

*The whole **idea** to slander John was... blah, blah...*

---

Thank you guys. *Plot*, *scheme*, and *intrigue* will do. *Scam* is fine as well, only a bit too informal for the context I need.

Comment: I realised the question was obvious immediately after I got the answers. I was exhausted, my mind was blank... Maybe it could be of some use when moved to the English Language Learners site (or shall I delete it?)

Answer (score 8):

According to Merriam-Webster, you can use ***[plot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plot)***:

> [ perhaps back-formation from *complot* ] : a secret plan for accomplishing a usually evil or unlawful end
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plot)*</sub>

Comment: I was just writing an answer about "plot" :) That's definitely the word I would use.

Comment: "Remember, remember the fifth of November,
Gunpowder treason and plot."

Answer (score 3):

I favor **scheme**. While it can refer to plans more generally, the connotation is commonly negative. From the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com/view/Entry/172317), bold for emphasis:

> 5 b. Hence, A plan of action devised in order to attain some end; a purpose together with a system of measures contrived for its accomplishment; a project, enterprise. **Often with unfavourable notion, a self-seeking or an underhand project, a plot** (cf. scheme v., scheming adj.), or a visionary or foolish project. Phrase, to lay a scheme.

And [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scheme):

> A scheme is also a secret and dishonest plan:

Villains have *schemes*. Con artists use *Ponzi schemes* or *Pyramid schemes*. A "scheme to slander" appears in [many search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scheme%20to%20slander%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-e). Hence:

> The whole **scheme** to slander John was ...

Comment: I think OP is looking for a SW that means *bad/harmful idea*. “To slander John was a scheme”?

Comment: @user067531 In American English, scheme is definitely a bad or harmful idea, e.g. "a Ponzi scheme". I do not think that "scheme" has the same pejorative connotation in British or other English usage though.

Answer (score 3):

If the idea is to benefit someone whilst harming someone else, "**ploy**" could also be used.

From [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ploy):

> A cunning plan or action designed to turn a situation to one's own advantage.

From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ploy?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld):

> a tactic intended to embarrass or frustrate an opponent

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *intrigue* could work in your context -

## Intrigue

> : make secret plans to do something illicit or detrimental to someone.

([From Oxford](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/intrigue))

Therefore,

> The whole ***intrigue*** to slander John was... blah, blah...

---

There is also *conspiracy* -

## Conspiracy

> a secret plan by a group to do something unlawful or harmful.

([From Oxford](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/intrigue))

Therefore,

> The whole ***conspiracy*** to slander John was... blah, blah...

Answer (score 1):

Another one that nobody has mentioned yet could be ['caper'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caper):

## Caper

> an illegal or questionable act or escapade

(From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caper))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ["scam"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scam):

> **scam** noun
>
> : a fraudulent or deceptive act or operation

M-W gives the example:

> Authorities said a parolee with a long history of identity theft and credit card **scams** masqueraded as a ride-share driver downtown and cleaned out the bank accounts of at least four people after gaining access to their bank cards.

So your sentence would be:

> "The whole scam to slander John was..."